# Django do not reload fixture for some test cases

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

For every test class I generated base `.json` fixture with data. It is pretty clear and fast way, because I do not need to spent time to generate data. Any additional data I can generate with factories directly in test.

```
class ProfileViewTests(MyProjectTestCase):
    fixtures = [os.path.join('compiled', 'test_companies_and_users.json')]

    def test1(self):
        pass
   
    def test2(self):
        pass
```

The issue that the loading of some fixtures is takes up to 15 sec., because they creating a huge piece of test data environment.

And now 70% of time I'm wasting to loading fixtures after every test case. The upside is because when we update objects we do not need care about flushing this data, but downside that time is increasing with every test.

I can move some data to `setUpTestData`, but revisit all this data for all this tests is almost impossible.

My question is there a decorator to say some tests cases do not reload fixtures, if they not modify data.

```
@do_not_flush_data_from_database_for_next_test_case_from_this_class
def get_users_test(self):
    pass
```

Because my test is only to `get` users, I do not want to waste 15 sec to reload my fixture file again for next test.

Or I need to dig into: "Why my fixtures are loading so slow?"

Answer (score 0):

> 70% of time I'm wasting to loading fixtures after every test case.

Just in case for clarification I will assume that *test **case*** is equal to *test **class***. Otherwise if *test case* is just single test then loading fixtures after every test could happen only if your `MyProjectTestCase` inherited from
`django.TransactionTestCase`. Because `TransactionTestCase` [setup fixtures](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3718bc5c8d738b392cb2f1c165dd5768b4c47151/django/test/testcases.py#L935) per-test, when `TestCase` [setup fixtures](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3718bc5c8d738b392cb2f1c165dd5768b4c47151/django/test/testcases.py#L1168) per-class.

---

In your case with different test classes with long load fixtures probably one of solution would use [custom test runner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/advanced/#using-different-testing-frameworks) which would call `loaddata` command for load fixtures only once per `./manage.py test` run.